# Making http request by tcp connection in go

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    conf := &tls.Config{}
    conn, _ := tls.Dial("tcp", "www.google.com:443", conf)
    data := []byte("GET / HTTP1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n")
    conn.Write(data)
    buf := make([]byte, 5000)
    conn.Read(buf)
    fmt.Println(string(buf[:]))
}
```

I am trying to make http request by raw tcp connection data, but get an error response of 400 Bad Request, what's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the data.

`HTTP1.1` should be `HTTP/1.1`.

---

I would like to share how I found the typo in the hope that it helps others.

When I want to address an issue that I'm not so familiar with, the first thing I do is to find out what it looks like when it works. I have used [nc](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/nc/) before, so I will try it first.

This is an example from the man page of `nc`:

```
$ printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc host.example.com 80
```

So I replaced `host.example.com` with `www.google.com` first:

```
$ printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc www.google.com 80
```

It works!

Then replace `HTTP/1.0` with `HTTP/1.1`. Still works!

Then add the `Host` header:

```
$ printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n" | nc www.google.com 80
```

Works!

Then copy the string from the question:

```
$ printf "GET / HTTP1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n" | nc www.google.com 80
```

Got `400 Bad Request` this time.

This is a big step forward! There is something wrong in the request. It's easy to spot the typo by comparing the two requests.

Finally, fix the typo in the original demo, and run the demo to verify that the issue has been addressed. Done!

Thanks for reading!